# Windows 7 - How to stop full path being displayed in Explorer taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Just went from XP to 7 and set my taskbar to show window titles. Problem is that explorer windows display the full path now, like "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\stuff" instead of just "stuff". I end up with a bunch of things in the taskbar that just say "C:\Users\Administrat..." which makes it hard to find windows. How do I change this?

Comment: You mean Title bar?, you can stretch the title bar over to the right to get more real estate.

Comment: @Moab, no, he means the taskbar buttons.

Comment: Yep I mean the taskbar buttons

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Will this option do what you want?

Click Tools -> Folder options -> View tab (if you don't see Tools in your explorer window you can press F10)

[image]

Comment: This did it, I didn't bother unticking that because I'm not on the classic theme, but it does affect the taskbar buttons either way. Kudos.

Comment: " it does affect the taskbar buttons either way." This is good to know, thanks for posting.

Answer (score -1):

I’m afraid, you cannot accomplish what you want. The taskbar buttons show whatever is in the window’s titlebar, so when you set windows to show the full path in the titlebar, they also show them in the taskbar buttons.

You *may* be able to find some third-party software that can (somehow) hack the taskbar/Explorer to show something other than the titlebar contents in the taskbar. However, a quick search turned up nothing, and as a programmer, I cannot even think of a (feasible) way to do it, and.